# Storing features layer with ArcGIS or as Geojson locally to access database data

Tags: ajax, geojson, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible to store a feature layer with just the basic information included with ArcGIS and be able to reference local data when a hosted feature is clicked?

For example, if I was looking at a map of hosted data, and it’s just had the coordinates and in the properties a master reference key (like parcel_id), could I then click the parcel like in the normal behavior of the basic JavaScript map, use the parcel_id for an Ajax request and then pull additional data from the local database and display it in the same pop-up? Could I edit data this way too? Or is this all only available for data/features only hosted with ArcGIS?

That being said, for what I am asking, would it be better to go the route of something like OpenLayers and using a Geojson file?

Answer (score 1):

If you load a [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html) onto the map, you can create a map click handler basically to listen for clicks on your map, do a hit test, and do some logic with whatever it clicked. Doesn't have to be a FeatureLayer, could be a [GeoJSONLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GeoJSONLayer.html) if you want. I believe it should be the same workflow for any type of layer.

Actually clicking on the map and getting the data from the feature would be setting up a click handler on the view ([MapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) or [SceneView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html) whichever you're working with) and then using a hit test based on the coordinates clicked.

Something to the effect of...

```
view.on("click", function(event) {
  view.hitTest({x: event.x, y: event.y}).then(function(response) {
    //response.results would hold the features you clicked
    if (response.results.length) {
      const graphic = response.results[0].graphic;
      // do something with the graphic
      const attributes = resposne.results[0].graphic.attributes;
      // do something with the attributes
    }
  });
});
```

You can see a similar example here for mouse hover events I adapted that from: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-hittest/ with more information about performing hit tests on maps and getting results back here in the documentation: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#hitTest